# Prevent running a script OR disable button - tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, button, tkinter, config

I am sure this question has been asked, and I came across some solutions but they are not working for me.
I am trying to disable a button in my tkinter gui if there is an error in input given by user.

There are two entry fields for entering time in seconds (t1 and t2 respectively). Once the entries are made, the user clicks on the Confirm button. 
What I now want to do is, if the time is not entered correctly, for example if t1 > t2, this will raise an error and the code will go into a function - time_error()

Once this error is raised, I want to disable the 'Go' button so that the script cannot be executed.

I am trying to disable this Go button in the time_error() function but I am unable to.

Following is my code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import pdb

root = tk.Tk()
color = '#aeb3b0'

IntroCanvas = tk.Canvas(height = 200, width = 400, bg = color)
IntroCanvas.pack()

# time error funtion **********    THIS IS NOT WORKING FOR ME    **************
def time_error():
    GoButton = tk.Button(root, text="GO!", command=go,bg = 'green', fg = 'white', width=4)
    GoButton.place(relx=0.4, rely=0.5)
    GoButton = tk.Button.configure(root,state = 'DISABLED')

# ****************************************************************************

# t1_init ************ ENTER FIRST TIME VALUE IN SECONDS ****
def blank_t1entry(event):
    t1entry.delete(0, "end") 
    return None 
t1entry = tk.Entry(width = 13)
t1entry.place(relx = 0.1, rely = 0.25)
t1entry.insert(0,"From seconds")
t1entry.bind("<Button-1>", blank_t1entry)

# t2_init ************ ENTER SECOND TIME VALUE IN SECONDS ****
def blank_t2entry(event): 
    t2entry.delete(0, "end") 
    return None 
t2entry = tk.Entry(width = 12)
t2entry.place(relx = 0.4, rely = 0.25)
t2entry.insert(0,"To seconds")
t2entry.bind("<Button-1>", blank_t2entry)

# ****** GET THE ENTERED TIME VALUES AND COMPARE THEM TO SEE IF THEY ARE APPROPRIATE, ELSE THROW ERROR ***
def confirmTime_comp():                
    global t1_comp_init, t2_comp_init

    if not ((str.isnumeric(str(t1entry.get()).replace('.','')))|(t1entry.get()=='From seconds')):
        time_error()
    else:
        t1_comp_init = t1entry.get()

    if not ((str.isnumeric(str(t2entry.get()).replace('.','')))|(t2entry.get()=='To seconds')):
        time_error()
    else:
        t2_comp_init = t2entry.get()
    # below lines are for throwing an error if t1 > t2 or t1 < 0
    pdb.set_trace()
    if not ('seconds' in t1_comp_init):
        if not ('seconds' in t2_comp_init):
            if float(t1_comp_init) >= float(t2_comp_init):
                time_error()
            elif float(t1_comp_init) < 0:
                time_error()

# ****** BUTTON TO CONFIRM TIME ENTRIES *******************
CompTimeButton = tk.Button(root, text="Confirm", command=confirmTime_comp,bg = 'green', fg = 'white')
CompTimeButton.place(relx=0.6, rely=0.25)

def go():
    printLabel = tk.Label(root, text = 'Go Button Pressed')
    printLabel.place(relx = 0.35, rely = 0.75)


GoButton = tk.Button(root, text="GO!", command=go,bg = 'green', fg = 'white', width=4)
GoButton.place(relx=0.4, rely=0.5)

root.mainloop()
```

Also, is there any other more elegant way to prevent running the script if user entries are incorrect?

Thank you

R

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a way to disable the button.
All it needed was:

```
def time_error():
    GoButton['state'] = tk.DISABLED
```